# Is there an automated, configurable way to organize many layers into a sprite sheet grid with exact pixel coordinates in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-scripting, grids, image-sprite

I have a huge grid of icons that need to be positioned so that I can write sprites out of them after I'm done.

Right now, I have so many layers, it'd take me forever to click on each one individually and specify the coordinates exactly.

Is there an easy way or a script that allows me to specify in pixels how far apart each icon should be from one another both horizontally and vertically (thereby creating a nice little grid for me with solid values without decimals) ?

Comment: FWIW, I usually just use grid lines evenly spaced. So if my largest icon is 20px x 20px I make a grid spaced 20px apart. Then it becomes very easy to write the CSS for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a PS script to make Sprite Sheets out of layers.
https://gist.github.com/jessefreeman/870172

```
// Put this file in Program Files\Adobe\Photoshop\Presets\Scripts\
// In PhotoShop menu File > Automate > Scripts: layersToSprite.js

// Arrange layers into a sprite sheet. 

if (documents.length > 0) 
{

    // --------------------------
    docRef = activeDocument;    
    var activeLayer = docRef.activeLayer;

    numLayers = docRef.artLayers.length;    
    var cols = docRef.width;

    var spriteX = docRef.width;

    // put things in order
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

    // resize the canvas
    newX = numLayers * spriteX;

    docRef.resizeCanvas( newX, docRef.height, AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT );

    // move the layers around
    for (i=0; i < numLayers; i++)
    {   
        docRef.artLayers[i].visible = 1;

        var movX = spriteX*i;

        docRef.artLayers[i].translate(movX, 0);

    }
}
```

You may also export all the layers as png images first then zip them and upload to http://spritegen.website-performance.org/ or any other sprite generator. That will automatically create the sprites for you.

Comment: This is also a nice sprite generator http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/ but auto alignment option is available for premium users. Will require a paid subscription for that feature.

Comment: for some reason, i hit an error when i try to run the script :-(

- The command “Transform” is not currently available.
Line: 117
->              elem.translate(newX, newY)

Comment: This script is based on this post: http://www.garagegames.com/community/blogs/view/11527
The author writes about compatibility: "Will work with CS, may work with 7 if you have the scripting plugin installed." But, as we are in 2015 already … this question should be solved. :-)